# Error in type.convert when reading data from CSV

Tags: r

I am working on a basketball project. I am struggling to open my data on R : 
https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_totals.html

I have imported the data on excel and then saved it as CSV (for macintosh). 
When I import the data on R I get an error message :

```r
"Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, : invalid multibyte string at '<e7>lex<20>Abrines' "
```

Comment: Code that throws the error, please?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work. The `readHTMLTable` function does give warnings due to the presence of null characters in column `Player`.

```
library(XML)

uri <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_totals.html"
data <- readHTMLTable(readLines(uri), which = 1, header = TRUE)

i <- grep("Player", data$Player, ignore.case = TRUE)
data <- data[-i, ]
cols <- c(1, 4, 6:ncol(data))
data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Check if there are `NA` values. This is needed because the table in the link restarts the headers every now and then and character strings become mixed with numeric entries. The `grep` above is meant to detect such cases but maybe there are others.

```
sapply(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

No, everything is alright. So write the data set as a CSV file.

```
write.csv(data, "nba.csv")
```

Comment: Right ! Thank you so much for your answer, its works ! :-))

Answer (score -1):

The file Encoding to Latin1 can help.
For example, to read a file in csv skipping second row:

```
Test=(read.csv("IMDB.csv",header=T,sep=",",fileEncoding="latin1")[-2,])
```